# How to copy and paste a text file in multiple folders

Tags: replace, copy, copy-paste

I have a text file in directory

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ivm.txt
```

And i wanted to paste this text file on multiple folders eg on this location-

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\File\
```

Total folders in couts are- 56
so i wanted to paste text file on all folders (because doing one by one is will be long)
and that text already present in some directory on that folder so give me any bash command or software suggestion to copy/replace

Comment: Do you have `cygwin`/`msys` or such linux-like environment ported on windows? Else, remove `bash` tag.